# tuple of references with conversion operators, g++ 5.x vs g++ 6.x

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, implicit-conversion

Given the following minimal example, g++ 5.4 compiles without complaining, but g++ 6.1 doesn't find a matching constructor for the `tuple`. The current VS 2015 compiler agrees with g++ 5.4 as well. Which compiler is correct?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

struct derived;
struct base
{
    operator derived & () &;
    operator derived const & () const &;
    operator derived && () &&;
};

struct derived : base {};

base::operator derived & () & { return *static_cast<derived *>(this); }
base::operator derived const & () const & { return *static_cast<derived const *>(this); }
base::operator derived && () && { return std::move(*static_cast<derived *>(this)); }

std::tuple<derived &&> test(base && b)
{
    return std::tuple<derived &&>(std::move(b));
}

int main(int,char**)
{
    auto d = std::get<0>(test(derived{}));
    return 0;
}
```

The base class provides an implicit conversion operator, so it should work as far as I can tell. If I change `test` to the following, neither compiler complains:

```
std::tuple<derived &&> test(base && b)
{
    return std::tuple<derived &&>(static_cast<derived &&>(std::move(b)));
}
```

Comment: `test()` returns a tuple of reference to object which gets deleted immediately after the call. Your code is not guaranteed to work. Anyway, what is the purpose of such code to begin with?

Comment: that's not the issue here. I added a `std::get<0>` so that doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: The implementation of `test` is still dangerous.

Comment: @Nawaz the purpose doesn't really matter here, but in the real code, base is a CRTP tag class used to limit what certain (variadic) template functions can operate on.

Comment: @Nawaz again, that is not the issue here. in the real code the tuple is forwarded to a different function that unpacks the tuple and returns a value.

Comment: `std::is_constructible<derived&&, base&&>::value` is `false` with both 5.3 and 6.2, which is a requirement for the constructor to work (as per the standard). This is (I think) wrong because `derived&& obj(std::declval<base&&>())` is well-formed for both (which is the definition of `is_constructible`). Maybe g++5.x was not checking this for the overload resolution?

Comment: @Holt makes sense, especially as the expected constructor was disabled due to an enable_if